# How to add combination memory to an Agent with tools?

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model, py-langchain

I want to create an Agent that will have 2 tools and a combined memory.

- Tools should be a `python_reply_tool` and my custom tool
  `search_documents`.
- I do not have problem adding the tools to the agent via `initialize_agent()` function
- But I cannot figure out how to add memory.

I have successfully created an example of combined memory:
llm_code = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model_name="gpt-4-0613") #gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613
llm_context = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.5, model_name="gpt-4") #gpt-3.5-turbo

```
chat_history_buffer = ConversationBufferWindowMemory(
    k=5,
    memory_key="chat_history_buffer",
    input_key="input"
    )

chat_history_summary = ConversationSummaryMemory(
    llm=llm_context, 
    memory_key="chat_history_summary",
    input_key="input"
    )

chat_history_KG = ConversationKGMemory(
    llm=llm_context, 
    memory_key="chat_history_KG",
    input_key="input",
    )

memory = CombinedMemory(memories=[chat_history_buffer, chat_history_summary, chat_history_KG])
```

How do I now pass this memory to the agent?
I tried via the `memory = memory` but without success.

Do I need to change the template somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Implement the code in below given url and you will be good to go.

BUT, do tell in reply by testing it that if it works for your chatgpt llm ? , because I am using google's flan-t5-large llm and I am getting some weird loop when I enter my text prompt.

https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/agents/how_to/sharedmemory_for_tools

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).